# Force mobile network connecting when WiFi and Mobile are available

Tags: android, mobile, wifi

```
public class InternetConnectionControl {

    private NetworkInfo networkInfo;

    private NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo() {

        if (networkInfo == null) {
            ConnectivityManager _cm = ServiceUtil.getConnectivityManager(MyApplication.getContext());
            networkInfo = _cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }

        return networkInfo;
    }

    public void setNetworkInfo(NetworkInfo networkInfo) {
        this.networkInfo = networkInfo;
    }

    private boolean isConnectedToWifi() {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    private boolean isConnectedToMobile() {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }


    public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {

        boolean isWifiConnected = isConnectedToWifi();
        boolean isMobileConnected = isConnectedToMobile();

        return isWifiConnected || isMobileConnected;

    }
}
```

I can check if wi-fi or mobile data is avaliable in my app, but how do I handle situation when both wi-fi and mobile data is active? How do I force using mobile network in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force mobile data on / off programaticaly above android 4.4 .This functionality  stopped for security reasons ,instead you can request the user using a dialog to enable the mobile data and then if he enable you can do your task.